# My motherboard's eSATA port has stopped working - any ideas?

Tags: motherboard, hardware-failure, esata

I've got an [ASRock 890FX Deluxe5](http://www.asrock.com/mb/overview.asp?model=890fx%20deluxe5) motherboard. The rear-panel eSATA port used to work, and now doesn't seem to register when I plug something in. (I have two hard drive docks which both stopped working with it, so I think it's the motherboard.)

I haven't made any hardware changes recently. And no software changes other than Windows updates etc. It seems odd that it would just suddenly stop working.

Is there anything I could try, or is it probably just permanently broken?

Comment: Try a LiveCD and see if it see drives attached to it?  Try the drives on another system?

Answer (score 0):

Have you done BIOS updates?

Check to see the port is still turned on in the BIOS settings.